# How does Hallar, the Firefletcher work with Multikicker?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Does [Hallar, the Firefletcher](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHallar%2c%20the%20Firefletcher%5d)'s ability trigger each time a multikicker spell is kicked? Or just once for a kicked spell?

Comment: I'm confused. Are you asking whether every "whenever you cast a spell" trigger would care about multikicker, or whether Hallar, in caring about kicker, cares about multikicker an additional number of times?

Comment: OK, I'm going to revert that edit for now. I think it obscures the primary point of the question.

Comment: Sorry, went a bit too far.

Answer (score 4):

The ability happens once.

[Hallar, the Firefletcher](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHallar%2c%20the%20Firefletcher%5d)'s ability trigger whenever you cast a spell, checking if the spell was kicked. Since multikicked spells are still a single spells, there is only one copy of the ability.

Answer (score 3):

It triggers once. While the "if it was kicked" clause limits when the ability triggers, the triggering condition is "a spell is cast".

Kicked spells —even those kicked multiple times— are still only cast once, so the ability will only trigger once.

Kicking or multikicking a spell simply affects the cost to cast that spell.

> 702.32a [...] “Kicker [cost]” means “You may pay an additional [cost] as you cast this spell.” [...]
>
> 702.32c [...] “Multikicker [cost]” means “You may pay an additional [cost] any number of times as you cast this spell.” [...]

Comment: It would be interesting if the card was worded "When a spell is kicked" as opposed to "When you cast a spell, if it was kicked." - I could see ambiguity there.

Comment: @corisKa, The answer is not as obvious, but it isn't ambiguous. A multikicker spell is considered kicked for each time the cost was payed (e.g. "Apex Hawks enters the battlefield with a +1/+1 counter on it for each time it was kicked."), so "Whenever a spell is kicked" would trigger multitple times for a multikicker spell for which the multikicker cost was payed multiple times.